# excel vba - concatenate two cell's content to another

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I have two columns that I need to combine an place in a third column. I've tried `=CONCATENATE(A1," ", B1)` but the result is wrong (it turns into some integer). Also, I need this in vba code cause I'm trying to automate something.

```
Column A   | Column B | 3rd column Desired result
2018-02-03 | 01:03:22 | 2018-02-03 01:03:22
2018-01-01 | 13:44:22 | 2018-01-01 13:44:22
2018-04-11 | 20:44:43 | 2018-04-11 20:44:43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both columns contain date (and time) objects, you can simply sum the values. Each date (and time) in Excel is converted to a number (day=1, hour=1/24). To complete the task with VBA:

```
Sub add_dates()
   ' loop over non-empty cells at 1st column
   i = 2
   Do While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
      Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i, 1) + Cells(i, 2)
      i = i + 1
   Loop

    ' Format range if necessary
    Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss;@"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need VBA for that!

You can easily convert the date to the desired format with `TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")` before concatenating.

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd")," ", TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

but then you have it as text and not as a date/time anymore! That means you cannot calculate with that date anymore.

#### So I suggest …

In the 3ʳᵈ column use the formula `=A1+B1`, and then format the 3ʳᵈ column with a custom format `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss;@` like shown below:

[image]

This way the 3ʳᵈ column remains a date/time you can calculate with.

#### Explanation

So why does a simple addition of `=A1+B1` work here?

- Dates in Excel are basically saved as the amount of days since `1900-01-01` (which is day `1`). So `2018-02-03` is the 43134ᵗʰ day since then.
- Time in Excel is saved as a part of `1` day, which means `01:03:22` is `0,04400463` of `1` day

So if we sum both (date value + time value): `43134 + 0,0440046 = 43134,0440046` and format this as a date, Excel understands this as `2018-02-03 01:03:22` (which is just `43134,0440046` days since `1900-01-01 00:00:00`).

Answer (score 0):

Before concantenate you should try to convert it to string

```
Sub test()
Dim s, ss, sss As String

s = Me.Range("H10").Value
ss = CStr(Me.Range("I10").Value)

Me.Range("J10").Value = s & ss

End Sub
```

Good luck

Comment: Note that `Dim s, ss, sss As String` only defines `sss As String` but `s` and `ss` remain of type `Variant`. You need to specify a type for **every** variable `Dim s As String, ss As String, sss As String` also `sss` is never used and therefore not necessary to declare.